# Android - create and re-use view in different activities

Tags: android, view, android-activity, code-reuse

I'm almost sure that the good practice is to use a View in one Activity, and not move it around too much (between Activities).

I mean, is it possible at all to create (programatically) a View, then keep it in some singleton object, and then try to add it to another View in a different Activity?

My personal feeling is that this is quite wrong practice, but I need to check it, there is a company requesting similar practice with their SDK, and before I oppose them, I want to be sure.

Any help appreciated,
Danail

Comment: I feel it should be possible, but for what purpose do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not build a [custom View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)?  Whether it is a simple widget that is used within a `ViewGroup`, or it is a `ViewGroup` of its own, it could be something that is reusable and customizable by you!

Obviously, you could provide different constructors/setters to customize the `View` to your liking. (ie, specify different bitmaps for backgrounds, different strings for title text...)